# Rails is not currently installed on this system - High Sierra, rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv, macos-high-sierra

To start I follow the exact steps from [Setup Ruby On Rails on
macOS 10.13 High Sierra](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.13-high-sierra), just like I have with every other version of mac/ubuntu.

So basically install homebrew, install rbenv ruby-build

add the following to bash profile and source it:

`if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`

then do

```
rbenv install 2.5.1
rbenv global 2.5.1
ruby -v
```

outputs:

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

do a `which ruby` to to make sure:

```
/Users/pdavies/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

run gem install

```
gem install rails -v 5.2.0
```

which outputs:

```
Successfully installed rails-5.2.0
Parsing documentation for rails-5.2.0
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

then a rehash and check version:

```
rbenv rehash
rails -v
```

outputs:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
$ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

found anther issue that suggested adding:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

to the bash profile, did that sourced it and tried again still nothing.  to check the output of `echo $PATH` was:

```
/Users/pdavies/.rbenv/shims:/Users/pdavies/.rbenv/bin:/Users/pdavies/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

Just to make sure i also did which gem incase i wasnt using the right one, output:

```
/Users/pdavies/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

when I do a which rails i get:

```
/usr/bin/rails
```

I found some blog that said to delete that, but I cant seem to do that either, i just get:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/rails
Password:
rm: /usr/bin/rails: Operation not permitted
```

This is a fresh install of OSX and the only way I can get it work is to downgrade the version of OSX that is installed, which is a pain in the ass!

Any help would be grateful

Thanks